# Twitter4j AccesToken with JavaFX Browser

Tags: java, twitter, oauth-2.0, javafx-2, twitter4j

I want to authentificate a user using an embedded browser with javafx. I can get the PIN (String) that twitter gives me but when I try to create the AccesToken it does not create it correctly.
(I can't get my token or tokenSecret, both null).

Here's my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Application.launch(args);
    }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
    primaryStage.setTitle("WebView test");

    WebView browser = new WebView();

    engine = browser.getEngine();

    twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();

    String url = requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();


    engine.load(url);

    engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>()
        {

            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState)
                {
                if (newState==State.SUCCEEDED && engine.getLocation().equals("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"))
                    {
                     String pin = engine.getDocument().getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("code").item(0).getTextContent();
                     printAccesToken(pin);
                    }
                }

        });

    StackPane sp = new StackPane();
    sp.getChildren().add(browser);

    Scene root = new Scene(sp);

    primaryStage.setScene(root);
    primaryStage.show();
    }



private void printAccesToken(String pin)
    {
    AccessToken accessToken = null;

    try
        {
        accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
        }
    catch (TwitterException e)
        {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());

    }

/*------------------------------------------------------------------*\
|*                          Attributs Private                       *|
\*------------------------------------------------------------------*/
private WebEngine engine;
private Twitter twitter;
private RequestToken requestToken;
private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "xxx";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxx";
```

I based myself on the code example that twitter4j offers, as far I can tell I am doing the exact same thing, only the String that I get is not inputed via keyboard, I get it directly from the browser ...

http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Based myself on Example #7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter API returns the pin in image format. It does not provide pin in string or int. That its. You can prompt user to enter pin manually.